# How to give delete privilige to a specific group while director has t sticky bit

Tags: linux, permissions, ftp

The system has a specific user *(user1)* for a specific service.
The service created a folder with permissions below

```
drwxrwsr-t  2 user1 group1  4096 Aug 25 14:24 test
```

I created another user for ftp service *(user2)* and added this user to group of the service user group named *group1*

*user2* is not be able to delete files under `test` folder because of the **t** sticky bit.

Is there a way to give permission to *user2* be able to delete files under `test` folder belong to *group1* group?

Comment: What's keeping you from removing the sticky bit?

Comment: @Larssend If I remove sticky bit, than any user has access to files could be remove files, I think. Also I'm trying to learn more about ACL.